# Java Code not working

Tags: java

```
public static long sum7()
{
    int c = 1;
    boolean isprime = true;
    long prime = 0;
    for (long i = 3; i <= Long.MAX_VALUE; i++)
    {
        for (long j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime == true)
        {
            c++;
        }
        if (c == 10001)
        {
            prime = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}
static Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(sum7());
}
```

I was trying out the following code for a project euler question(Q7), i'm supposed to locate the 10001st prime number but it was just not working. The build is successful but it is not showing anything Please help. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Define "not working" please. Most of us are terrible at reading minds and have no idea what the code is supposed to be doing and not doing and what it isn't supposed to be doing and is doing.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you said what this function is trying to do... "project euler question" means nothing to me.

Comment: what error are you getting or what you want your answer to be?

Comment: guys, thanks for the feedback, and sorry for the misunderstanding....just edited it now

Comment: Antinomy's answer should fix your bugs. To do your task more efficient I would rather implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, so I have to guess based on the code. I'm assuming that you wish to find the 10001th prime number.

First off, you forgot to set `isprime` back to true at the end of the loop. As it is now, it will permanently be false after the first iteration, meaning that 3 is the only prime detected and you'll loop all the way up to 2^63 (effectively infinite) after that and eventually return 0.

You can solve the problem and also scope your variable better by moving `boolean isprime = true;` to the start of the loop. You might as well move `prime` into the loop while you're at it and change the `if c==10001` bit to just return directly.

Secondly, `c = c++;` isn't correct. You're incrementing the variable and then resetting it to the old value. You should either do `c++;` or `c = c + 1`.

Comment: On a side note:- you don't need `if (isprime == true)`, just `if (isprime)` is enought.

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be set to true in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad. didn't see that its a nested loop. :(\